# CSS not displaying .custom-logo properly, is PHP the problem?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have tried several things, ultimately what should work to allow the graphic to display at full image size is this:

```
.custom-logo {
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

It's not working. It will only display the .custom-logo at 225 x 225 for whatever reason and I cannot seem to override the WP template. I'm not a PHP expert, but from what I can tell from inspecting the image, it seems to have something to do with the template PHP code. Here is the code that is displaying the logo. Any thoughts to allow the image to display at full size would be helpful! Clearly there's something I'm missing.

```
<div class="site-branding">
<?php has_custom_logo() ? the_custom_logo() : ''; ?>

<div class="site-branding-text">
    <?php if ( is_front_page() ) : ?>
        <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
    <?php else : ?>
        <p class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></p>
    <?php
    endif;

    $description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $description || is_customize_preview() ) : ?>
        <p class="site-description"><?php echo $description; /* WPCS: xss ok. */ ?></p>
    <?php
    endif; ?>
</div><!-- .site-branding-text-->
```

Thanks!

Comment: No, the fault is not going to lie with PHP. What are the dimensions of the raw logo image file? What are the dimensions of the space available to it? Can you link us to an example of your page so we can take a look?

Comment: @ceejayoz It's a CSS issue, check my anaswer. Why would the raw image size matter to CSS? It can be resized just the same as anything else.

Comment: @Laif Because `max-width` on a small image won't make it suddenly into a big image. If the raw image is 225x225, a `max-size` of `100%` won't make it any bigger. You and I agree, and your answer is good; I think you misunderstood my point.

Comment: @ceejayoz Max width won't, width will. max-width will never change the width to expand it. [see here](https://codepen.io/Libruhh/pen/gObvwLg).

Comment: An empty codepen?

Comment: My bad haha. [here](https://codepen.io/Libruhh/pen/gObvwLg)

Comment: "max-width will nevber change the width" We agree, which is why I asked what the dimensions of the logo image file are.

Comment: @ceejayoz You're right, disregard me lmao, totally misunderstood what you were saying. Also not sure why I can't type today.

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention I had width set to 100% as well... I'm not exactly sure what the problem is, but I can't get this image to appear any larger than 225 x 225 and I can't figure out what is setting that parameter...

Comment: I've tried several image sizes... 1500 x 1500, 600 x 600, 9960 x 9960 lol...

Comment: @JoshuaTanner Could you please create a reproducible issue with just html and css? The way the image displays on the screen has absolutely nothing to do with PHP. Please copy the HTML and CSS generating this issue so we can see what's going on.

Comment: <img width="225" height="225"
  src="http://graphic.png"
  class="custom-logo" alt="Post Tenebras Lux bible Rebinding"
  srcset="http://graphic.png 225w, http://graphic.png 150w, http://graphic.png 100w, http://graphic.png 50w"
  sizes="(max-width: 225px) 100vw, 225px">

Comment: @JoshuaTanner Your `width="225" height="225"` are going to override whatever's in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

`max-width` doesn't set the width of the image, it sets the max width it is allowed to resize to.

Use `width: 100%;` to set the width of your image to 100% of it's space.

```css
img{
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#div1 img{
  max-width: 100%;
}

#div2 img{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
max-width: 100%
<div id="div1">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
</div>
width: 100%
<div id="div2">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
</div>
```